# Grammar.txt not found pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I have `python-3.5.0-embed-amd64` on my system and `pip`, `pip3` also.
They are also defined in path.

Now when I try to install : **pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu**

It gives me error saying :

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'e:\\software\\python-3.5.0-embed-amd64\\python35.zip\\lib2to3\\Grammar.txt'
```

Full error : [here](https://pastebin.com/VxQRXKYj)

But as you can see, it it present actually:

[image: grammer.txt not found pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu]

**What is the actual error here, what should I do?**

Comment: Have you tried not using the embedded version of Python?

Comment: that solved the problem, although i had to add another path for a cuda `.dll` and rename it ... @cricket_007 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) mentioned, it worked with **not using embedded version of 3.5 specifically**.